# TSQL find records with different writing in another table

Tags: t-sql, substring, sql-server-2012, union

I have a "MasterTable" with the following records:

MasterTable:

```
Col1
PX02894
PX02895
PX02896
PX02897/98
```

From the lookup table I want to get the Col2 links, keeping the formatting of the MasterTable, represented as the Output table below.

LookupTable:

```
Col1            Col2
PX02894-PX02895 Link001
PX02896         Link002
PX02897-PX02898 Link003
```

OutputTable:

```
Col1         Col2
PX02894      Link001
PX02895      Link001
PX02896      Link002
PX02897/98   Link003
```

As you can see the writing is different "/" and "-".

I've tried with

> len(col1) > 7 THEN LEFT(col1,5) + RIGHT(col1,2)

but that's wrong. Do I need a Union first?

Here's a [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f089/5)

What do I need to do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is lookup table always just two Ids, i.e. would PX02900-PX02949 be a possible entry?

Comment: it's always just two ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m.col1,l.col2
From MasterTable m
inner join linkTable l
On (Substring(m.col1,1,7) = SubString(l.col1,1,7)) or (Substring(m.col1,1,7) = Substring(l.col1,9,7))
```

should do it as long as you can trust the data formating. if not a few more checks e.g

```
Substring(l.col1,8,1) = '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this --
This works in sybase-- if you using SQL server find alternate functions

select substring(col1,1,(charindex("-",col1)-1)),
UNION
select substring(col1,(charindex("-",col1)+1),char_length(col1))

Thanks,
Gopal